# É possível fazer testes unitários em funções do PHP?

Tags: php, testes-de-unidade, phpunit

Com PHPUnit podemos executar testes unitários em código orientado a objetos.
Existe algo parecido para funções do PHP?

Comment: Claro que sim, você escreve o que quiser dentro de cada método do teste, o que é esperado no resultado é o valor para o assert, não tem segredo, phpunit pode ser escrito em OOP, mas o conteudo dentro de cada método pode ser qualquer coisa.

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento. Com base no seu comentário, fiz alguns testes e cheguei à resposta que compartilho para dúvidas similares de outros usuário.

Answer (score 1):

Com base no que o [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento) comentou, fiz alguns testes e "descobri" que dá pra testar funções com o PHPUnit.

Criei uma função chamada `cfg_pdo_user()`que deve retornar uma *string* com o valor "root".

Para testar, criei uma classe `MyTest` com um método `test_cfg_pdo_user()`

```php
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_cfg_pdo_user()
    {
        $this->assertEquals('root', cfg_pdo_user());
    }
}
```

Depois, bastou rodar o comando para executar os testes:

`PS C:\xampp\htdocs\mymoney> .\vendor\bin\phpunit --bootstrap .\init.php .\tests\MyTest.php`

A opção `--bootstrap .\init.php` incluiu um arquivo que faz a inclusão do arquivo com a função testada.

O resultado foi o seguinte:

```
PHPUnit 9.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 84 ms, Memory: 4.00 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

**Conclusão:** é possível aplicar testes unitários com *PHPUnit* diretamente em funções, sem depender de uma estrutura orientada a objetos.